# What is the Touch UI replacement of xtype tableedit2?

Tags: dialog, aem, aem-6, aem-touch-ui, adobe-exprience-manager

We are migrating Classic UI components to Touch UI components in AEM

There is a xtype = "tableedit2" (https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.TableEdit2)

I have tried

```
sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/table"
```

with columns defined but is not coming.

Can anyone tell me the replacement for tableedit2 or how to implement granite table with an example because I was not able see any examples of granite table.

Thanks in advance.